# cant read post request response using javscript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I have an html form.  The form sends login request to server. The html response from server is put in an iframe.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").click(function(event){

$("#dummyframe").on('load',function() {
 
var myiframe = $("#dummyframe").val();
var iframedocument = myiframe.contentDocument;
var response = iframedocument.queryselector("pre");
var  errormessage = '{"code":500,"message":"入力項目に誤りがあります","data":{}}';
if (response == errormessage ){
alert('wrong password');
}
else {
alert('password is ok');
}

});
});
});
```

```html
<iframe name="dummyframe" id="dummyframe" style="display: none;"></iframe>

    <form  method="post" target="dummyframe" action="https://kintai.jinjer.biz/v1/sign_in">

    <input name="company_code" type="hidden" value="1234" /> 
    <input  name="email" type="hidden" value="1234" /> 
    <input  name="password" type="hidden" value="1234" />
    <input type="submit" value= "submit" id= "submit" /> 
    </form>
```

I want to read response from the server to validate password. If I get error message from server, I want to alert "wrong password" in my html page. Am I missing something? It doesn't work. The code doesn't seem incorrect. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please explain this code: `var myiframe = $("#dummyframe").val();` how is dummyframe value a DOM element?

Comment: sorry I m very new to this. Do you have any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your script to below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(event){
         $("#dummyframe").on('load',function() {

             var myiframe = $("#dummyframe");
             var iframedocument = myiframe.contentDocument;
             if (iframedocument.document) iframedocument = iframedocument.document;
             var response = iframedocument.queryselector("pre").innerHTML;
             var  errormessage = '{"code":500,"message":"入力項目に誤りがあります","data":{}}';
             if (response == errormessage ){
                 alert('wrong password');
             }
             else {
                 alert('password is ok');
             }

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi @Rav -  If this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it by clicking the check-mark. This may be useful to anybody else in the community.